# How to change MySQL column values within selected date range

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Im facing a problem with change column value within selected date range. Simply i want to disable all products (set 0 value instead of 1) within a desired date range like below:

**My query is**

```
SELECT * FROM `product` 
WHERE `date_add` > '2015-08-01 00:00:00'
AND  `date_upd` < '2016-08-01 00:00:00' 
SET `active` = 0
```

**But PHPMyAdmin throws error**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET `active` = 0 ORDER BY `product`.`date_upd` ASC LIMIT 0, 30'
>   at line 5

Comment: Use UPDATE query not SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Update Query Instead of select.

[The UPDATE statement is used to update records in a table.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

```
update `product`
set `active`='0' 
WHERE `date_add` > '2015-08-01 00:00:00'
AND  `date_upd` < '2016-08-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks. Soooo stpd question from my side! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to use an `UPDATE` Statement to change a value

```
UPDATE product
SET active = 0
WHERE date_add > '2015-08-01 00:00:00'
AND  date_upd < '2016-08-01 00:00:00'
```

Here's to documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Thanks. Soooo stpd question from my side! ;)